# How do you call a fifth-year student in college terminology?

Tags: word-usage

In US College terminology, they call a fourth-year college student a Senior. Most of their reasons were because you are a senior when you graduate from college. How about those courses who have 5-year course with 2-semester only, like 5th-year college student? What's the term they are categorized?

Comment: When I was at RPI <mumble> years ago, the Architecture degree program was a five-year sequence. Architecture students _never_ called themselves 'junior' or 'senior'; they were 'third year' through 'fifth year'. 'Freshman' and 'sophomore' were common but not universal because those two years were mostly taken by 'common core' courses that _all_ students had to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the above answer, the US does not have a standardized word for a 5th year student. Typically, students would just say "This is my 5th year" or "This is my final year." Some students consider themselves to be juniors for two years or seniors for two years, but that's more about culture and less about language.

Some slang terms to describe 5th year students do exist though. Here are some of them:

- Super Senior (This is most common, many Americans will know what you mean if you say you're a super senior)
- Hang-overs (Cornell University uses this term)
- Stay-overs (I've heard this exactly once)
- Extras (I've heard a student from Florida use this term)

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no single word corresponding to "senior" for a fifth-year student. Such a person would most likely simply be called a "fifth-year student", or possibly a "fifth-year senior". The latter might be more likely when such a situation is a rare exception, When many or most students are in a program for 5 years or more, I would expect "Nth-year student" to be the usual for for all students, and the one-word forms not to be used often.